# Flutter ios - app works on simulator fails on deploying to iphone - library not found for -lFirebaseCore

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter

As the title states I can run my app on ios simulator but when I attempt to deploy my app to the iphone through Xcode I get the error message

```
:-1: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ? This is my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  http: "^0.11.3+16"

  crypto: any
  validate: "^1.6.0"
  json_annotation: ^0.2.4
  image_picker: "^0.4.1"
  firebase_messaging: ^2.1.0 
  device_info: ^0.2.1
  location: ^1.4.1
  cached_network_image: "^0.4.1"
  mutex: #"^0.0.1"
  logging: "^0.11.3+1"
  uuid: ">=1.0.0"
  web_socket_channel: ^1.0.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  json_serializable: ^0.5.2
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly, but you have to include either `firebase_database` or `firebase_auth` in `pubspec.yaml`. I'll make a test and update this later.

Comment: sorry, they are plug-ins. add them in `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd` into the iOS folder of your flutter projects directory and run

```
pod install
```